# I have a Recyclerview and a list with 5000 items but I only want to load 100 items at a time

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I've implemented a `Recyclerview` in my test app. Currently I pull around 5000 items of data into a model and load my view with this list. Everything is great, and performs nicely but I don't particularly want to load all 5000 items. I would prefer to load 100 items and once the user hits the bottom, load the next 100 and essentially make it an ever growing list.

I can implement `onScrollListener` against the `Recyclerview` to do the detection of when I've reached the end but my issue (as simple as this sounds) is, what is the best way to tell the `Recyclerview` to load only 100 until I say?

My Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ImageFeed> mFeedList;

    public MyAdapter(List<ImageFeed> feedList) {
        this.mFeedList = feedList;
    }

    public void setFeedList(List<ImageFeed> feedList) {
        mFeedList = feedList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup vGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(vGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_list, vGroup, false);
        return new MyAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String mTitle = mFeedList.get(i).getTitle();

        ...//Do other stuff
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFeedList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected ImageView mImageView;
        protected TextView mTitle;
        protected ProgressBar mLoader;
        private int mItemId;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
            this.mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            this.mLoader = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mLoaderProgress);

            this.mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setItem(int item) {
            this.mItemId = item;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Image view clicked: " + this.mItemId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), this.mItemId + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thinking the scenario out I would have thought passing a smaller list is a possibility but it doesn't feel completely right.

Comment: yes, it is actually  a common *pattern*. Maybe you could start preloading it when you are x elements far from the bottom

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the question, but this doesn't seem specific to RecyclerView. If you've already done the work of loading 5,000 items, you've already done the heavy lifting.  If not, I think you're on the right track by implementing the onScrollListener and simply loading subsequent pages of data when a user reaches the bottom.

Comment: It's a common problem but I don't know of a common / simple solution. The standard adapter concept has nothing included that would tell you which part of the backing model is required or currently displayed. It's just for "adapting" from *loaded* data to displayed items. You could solve e.g. by implement auto loading via scroll listeners or special items that when displayed (a list item that says "loading..") trigger loading, manual paging via buttons/swiping/.. or even by displaying dummy items while asynchornously loading the actual items (image loaders do that kind of thing).

Comment: Ok so from the sounds of it the best way to do this is to not do the initial 5000 load. The better approach is to do this in smaller parts and let the scroll listener perform additional fetch requests when nearing the bottom. Ok this sound like one of the thoughts I was having. I'll play around with this and get back with an update. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok so this wasn't particularly difficult after all - I think my main issue was over thinking the scenario...

So the first thing I do is get the appropriate data (in this case through JSON) and store it in a JSON array for manipulation later - currently I'm still getting the full set (I.e 5000) but that's easily changeable.

This is done through an AsyncTask with an indeterminate progress bar. Once it's completed, I only parse the JSON to 20 elements and load this into the adapter.

Once done I have my Recyclerview.onScrollListener....

```
mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                mOnScreenItems = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                mTotalItemsInList = llm.getItemCount();
                mFirstVisibleItem = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (mLoadingItems) {
                    if (mTotalItemsInList > mPreviousTotal) {
                        mLoadingItems = false;
                        mPreviousTotal = mTotalItemsInList;
                    }
                }

                if (!mLoadingItems && (mTotalItemsInList - mOnScreenItems) <= (mFirstVisibleItem + mVisibleThreshold)) {
                    new AsyncLoadTask().execute();
                    mLoadingItems = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

        });
```

When it nears the end or hits the bottom a new AsynTask is kicked off to load additional items into the list. The `onPostExecute()` then updates the adapter through its `mMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method resulting in a nice smooth update. A lot of cleaning up to do but the basics are there.

Thanks for the direction guys!

Comment: nice one dude. However I had to do one thing extra. Instead of using mMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); I used mMyAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position); This way the adapter would not be taking up memory for already loaded items.